# Добавить тегу класс при клике на него jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На всех страница сайта есть меню в виде списка `ul` `li` `a`.

Можно ли при клике по ссылке тегу `li` всегда добавлять класс `active`, но только тому элементу на странице, по которому был клик?

```
<ul">
    <li><a href="#">Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Title</a></li>
</ul>
```

Прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: "Можно ли ...?" - Можно.

Comment: HTML и код мы должны сами придумать?

Comment: Поправил вопрос. Помогло?

Comment: Не особенно. *(3 символа нужно...)*

Answer (score 1):

Для доступа к "родителю" используйте [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), для поиска среди всех "родителей" используйте [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), и, наконец, для поиска среди "братьев" используйте [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```js
$('ul.menu a').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Title</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Логично то что после клика по ссылке страница должна перезагружаться и класс должен оставаться.

Comment: Где об этом сказано в вопросе? У вас теги: javascript, html, jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать через get параметры, при загрузке страницы брать параметр из url и проверять если есть такой параметр в вашем ul li a, то к родительскому тегу a/li добавлять класс active. Если это не очень хороший вариант, то объясните почему

```
<li><a href="link1?param=link1">Link1</a></li>
```

далее js проверка